# Passing parameters to a custom Devise mailer with Mandrill

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mandrill

I have a customer mailer set up with devise as you can see below:

```
class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer

  default from: "hello@example.com"

  def mandrill_client
    @mandrill_client ||= Mandrill::API.new MANDRILL_API_KEY
  end


  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})

    template_name = "user-confirm-account"
    template_content = []
    message = {
        to: [{email: record.email}],
        subject: "Confirm Your account",
        merge_vars: [
            {rcpt: record.email, 
            vars: [
                {name: "CONFIRM_ACCOUNT_LINK", content: "#{root_url}users/confirmation?confirmation_token=#{token}"},
            ]
            }
        ]
    }

    mandrill_client.messages.send_template template_name, template_content, message
  end


  def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    template_name = "user-forgot-password"
    template_content = []
    message = {
        to: [{email: record.email}],
        subject: "Password Reset",
        merge_vars: [
            {rcpt: record.email, 
            vars: [
                {name: "PASSWORD_RESET_LINK", content: "#{root_url}users/password/edit?reset_password_token=#{token}"},
            ]
            }
        ]
    }

    mandrill_client.messages.send_template template_name, template_content, message
  end

  def unlock_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    # code to be added here later
  end   

end
```

This works great. I did this so that I could customise confirmation emails sent by Mandrill. In order to send the confirmation email I call the following:

```
@user.send_confirmation_instructions
```

This works but I want to be able to send a different template for confirmation_instructions depending on a parameter I pass to the mailer. Such as `source=contactform`. How would I include a parameter in my `@user.send_confirmation_instructions` code and then retrieve it in the mailer? Thanks! :)

Comment: i think this article might help you: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-send-transactional-emails-from-rails-with-mandrill

Comment: Doesn't quite touch on what I am after with manually sending the emails unfortunately.

Comment: you can use [render_anywhere](https://github.com/yappbox/render_anywhere) to get the content template to mandrill Api.